# Can't create File Geodatabase on one specific drive

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arccatalog

I can create a file geodatabase in ArcCatalog 10.2 and 10.4 in C:/ drive and in 2 network drives but on the 3rd network drive when you try to create a file geodatabase (fgdb) by either right clicking and selecting new>file GDB, or Python script or by using FME. I get an error saying I don't have permission to create a FGDB and it disconnects the drive, not only in ArcCatalog but also if I try to access the drive through Windows Explorer. The only way to re-map the drive is to log out and log back in again.

Upon reopening you can see a new fgdb but it won't open stating it is corrupt or created with a different version to the current version.

It gets stranger because I can create a fgdb using FME's File Geodb-Open API.
I have checked with the network administrators and I have full read/write/execute on the drive and I have no problems creating a personal database .mdb file, shapefiles or executing Python scripts. The administrators have said the drive is fine and there should be no permissions issues and ArcCatalog, ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro all work fine so it doesn't appear to be a software issue either.

There is a slight difference in the size of the corrupted fgdb 115kb compared to 122kb for a normal empty and this appears to be down to the a00000004gdbtable and a00000004.gdbtablx.

How can I fix this problem?

In the short term I can create a fgdb in C drive and copy it across but that's not a preferred long term option. And I would prefer not to have to rebuild my machine.

This question has also been posted on ESRI's geonet website.

Comment: sounds like a group policy set on the network share itself. can you create any other type of files on the drive? .txt or .docx ect...

Comment: Possibly a network latency issue?

Comment: yes, I can create text files, docs and everything else except file geodatabases, I should also add the problem only started about a month ago. Before that it was fine but apperently no changes have been made in the last month to that drive.

Comment: Can you create a mapped drive to the network drive on your PC?

Comment: yes, no problems

Comment: Possible interference from a virus/malware scanner?

Comment: @Banger after you map a drive, can you make a folder connection in ArcCatalog to the mapped drive and create a file geodatabase this way?

Comment: @enolan, I have no trouble creating a new folder with Arc Catalog but the same problem with a fgdb created inside the newly created folder, thank you for your suggestions

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines as @NULL.Dude that it is a group policy setting but as I can create and run every other type of files including .bat files and cmd files I can't see how a specific group setting would affect just file gdb's,

Comment: interesting aside, I can create a arcpro project file which contains a fgdb inside it.

Comment: Also no problem with network latency and the time on the server the drive is on appears correct.

Comment: Please include a link to where you posted this question to the Esri Community.

Answer (score 2):

Andy was correct. It was the virus scanner, eventually one of our team members got an error message indicating interference from the virus protection software, we managed to persuade the IT department to temporarily remove the software and the problem was solved.